# using linq select inside method

Tags: .net, linq, select, lambda, func

I have a List which contains Properties like Id, Name, Age.
With Linq, I can select one or many properties with .Select(x => x.Name,x.Age)
and got an Enumeratble with only these properties.

Now, I need to do this choose inside a method. I tried to use the func but have trouble to open the method:

```
 void myMethod<T,TSelection>(List<T> Persons, Func<T, TSelection> index) {

 var Index = list.Select(index);
...
    }
```

How can I now open the method? I thought something like that:

```
 myMethod(list,(list, t => t.Age))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the lambda as the second argument:

```
myMethod(list, t => t.Age)
```

The runtime will coerce your lambda into a delegate compatible with the `Func` parameter. If the compiler cannot figure out your types, then you may have to specify the types on your lambda. This is usually only an issue if you are using a generic type parameter as a return type--you should be fine in this particular case.

If you want to select multiple properties without selecting a new instance of the original type, then you would select a new anonymous object (e.g. `new { }`). You can pick the properties you care about within the lambda:

```
myMethod(list, t => new { t.Age, t.Name });
```

Comment: Thank you, It work without "list,..." part. But, how can I select many properties?

Comment: The syntax you show in your original code is not correct for selecting multiple properties. I believe what you are after is an anonymous object. I've edited the answer to show how you would project that out.